# Slack challenge parameter issue with ngrok

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've been trying to learn how to build a slack bot. I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gHvqXrfjuo

I ran ngrok on http 5000, and I have my python file running on the same port.

I'm trying to add event subscriptions, but the link doesn't respond with a challenge parameter. I get a 403 forbidden response from the post request. I currently live in a student accommodation, so I don't have my own private Internet connection from a router, but I use something called ASK4 which is the same sort of specialist ISP that hotels use I'm assuming. I thought it was my firewall at first, but after turning that off, I'm starting to think it's the nature of my connection itself. Any Ideas?

```
import slack
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

app = Flask(__name__)
slack_event_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(os.environ['SIGNING_SECRET'], '/slack/events', app)

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])
client.chat_postMessage(channel='#acme-explosives', text="Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Comment: My bad, I didn't really think this was a code issue, but I've attached my bot's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change Ngrok port and application port, it will help